# AWS Lambda - how to identify duplicate messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, mqtt, amazon-sqs, aws-iot

Since several of the triggers for AWS Lambda can only guarantee message delivery "at least once" (SQS and IoT with QoS=1), I wonder what's the best way to identify a duplicate message and ignore it.

I can see that I currently get several duplicate messages, triggering my lambdas twice, causing noise and invalid data as a consequence.

In my client, I solve it by just storing a list of message IDs that I've processed, but in the Lambdas, I have nowhere to store a state.

Of course I could maintain a DB table of processed message IDs but it seems like overkill to me (and probably adds extra billed runtime to the lambdas). A simple key/value store service in memory would be enough.

What other solutions are you guys using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you don't want to use a DB but dynamodb can work well for this kind of thing. If you have something you can use as a good partition key then it will still be quite performant. It will still add a very small amount of time to your lambda run time and, of course, you will be charged for your dynamodb capacity & data. I use this successfully to discard duplicate messages.

The other thing that might be worth looking into would be elasticache which has memcached and redis versions. This would be faster - if performance is a particular focus - but is not persistent like DynamoDB.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Since the time of asking, I've switched to an SNS/SQS based setup, with filter policies on the SNS subscriptions and FIFO enabled for the SNS queues. It works great so far, even though it's not as elegant as the MQTT solution, but the AWS implementation of MQTT seems to have its disabilities.

I've also been looking more into DynamoDB (for other purposes) and it could definitely be used, since it seems to be really fast for small objects with well defined keys.

Comment: @EsbenvonBuchwald How?  SNS does not work with FIFO SQS queues though....

Comment: All messages published to SNS topics in my setup are handled by lambdas. And these lambdas are sending messages to FIFO queues, with the message ID as deduplication ID.

So, even though SNS may invoke the lambda twice for the same message, the queue will only deliver the result once, since the deduplication ID is the arbitrary message ID that the sender used when creating the SNS message